# TestFx4 / JavaFx - How to get TableView Cell graphic

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablecell, testfx

I´m trying find out how to get a graphic of a specified cell of a tableView. My scenerio looks like this:

[image: TableView cells icons]

I know i can get a value of a specified cell, which would look something like this:

```
getCellValue(TableView table, int column, int row) {
   ((TableColumn)table.getColumns().get(column)).getCellObservableValue(row).getValue();   
}
```

but i did not find out how to get other TableCell attributes, namely graphics, to test, if the cell gets appropriate icon after validation.

Comment: hmm .. it's been a while, you probably solved this already, but actually I don't quite understand the problem: TableViewMatchers has methods to match the textual cell content against strings, you could implement analogous methods to match graphical cell content against whatever node.

Comment: Sounds like a good point, I will definitely try it once i get back into testing javaFx. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward solution is to define ids for your icons and lookup them in your tests.

To bind icon ids with specific col and row you may use a special id format for this: `colN_rowN_iconName`.

**UPDATE:**

To find a specific `TableCell` object by id we may set an id in the `upateItem()` method:

```
    return new TableCell<AspectsTableRowData<?>, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(final String item, final boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            setId("TODO set my id");
        }
    };
```

Comment: This could be the way, but isn't there really any other way? I would like to get specified TableCell object, but i don't know how. Maybe its not possible and the approach is bad..

Comment: I updated my post how to get specified `TableCell` object.

Comment: Ok, it looks like there is no way to get, lets say, table cell at row 1 column 3, if it has no id? In other words, i can't solve it with no changes in application code?

Comment: I don't know such way.

Comment: have a look at TableViewMatchers: there are internal methods to match textual cell content against strings - copy those for graphical content. The one drawback might be, that it doesn't seem to test against the actual cell, but against a newly created cell, but most of the time that shouldn't make a difference.